# Just like in FB Ads we can use same pixel across multiple ad accounts, Can we do the same exact thing with google ads?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api, google-ads-script, google-tag-manager-server-side, google-ads-data-hub

I am a Facebook ads expert and i've been using the same pixel across mutiple ad accounts for my Roofing clients and I am looking to do the same thing with Google, I am not much knowlegable about google ads but is it possible that we use the same pixel(or GTM) across different ad accounts? The goal is to track the conversion data across different ad accounts which will ultimately help us to drive lower CPL. I hope i can do that. What is your opinion?

I tried Fb ads and i used the same pixel codes and conversion APIs to track the progress using the same pixel data and I am looking to do the same thing with google but i don't know how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the same by creating an MCC (Google Ads Manager Account) for all the different Google Ads Account you'll manage.

Once you have it created, create the conversion actions you'd like to track across all ad accounts. Then generate a Google tag for the MCC account, and this is what you'll use to implement on sites via gtag or GTM.

Here's the [documentation](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/3030657) that explains it. Hope that answers your question.